# JavaScript Audio Click Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hey there i have this small script to make it play audio when i click an image but it is not working. Mind helping me fix?

```
<img src="tupac.png" width="600" height="420" alt="" onclick="song.play()"/> 

<script>
var song = new audio();
song.src = "tupac meme.wav";
</script>
```

I cut some parts out but i don't see the problem in the code. Could it be the wav file? I would really appreciate some help. And thanks!

Comment: When you click on the img, do you get an error in the browsers console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`song` does not appear to be defined at `onclick="song.play()`. You can create a function to call at click on `<img>` to define `song` and call `.play()` at `oncanplaythrough` event of `<audio>` element.

Edit, Updated

`new audio()` should be `new Audio()`

```
<script>
function playSong() {
  var song = new Audio();
  song.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    this.play()
  }
  song.src = "tupac meme.wav";
}
</script>
<img src="tupac.png" width="600" height="420" alt="" onclick="playSong()"/>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pffhz4ot/

Comment: I have the code in but i am unable to click the image? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "unable to click the image?" ? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: @TechCentral Substitute `new Audio()` for `new audio()`; "a" should be uppercase, see updated post

Comment: Thanks a ton! Everything works now (Don't you just hate forgetting one letter) But do you think there is a way to make it so that your mouse changes to the about to click finger? http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2015/10/mouse-click-stock-100622925-large.png (I put in picture for Reference)

Comment: @TechCentral You can use `css` `:hover` at `img` element, `cursor` property, e.g., `img:hover {cursor:pointer}`

Comment: Yeah but that makes every image have it. Is there a way for only that one image? Should i put an id on it?

Comment: @TechCentral That was "for example"; you can use selector `img[src="tupac.png"]:hover {cursor:pointer}`, or set a unique `id` at the image

Comment: Sorry to bother you for one last time but, It works fine in Edge but on chrome i am able to click the image and it plays the sound but i am unable to see the cursor change. Any insight?

Comment: @TechCentral The `cursor` changes at chromium at `:hover` here https://jsfiddle.net/pffhz4ot/1/

Comment: it works in jsfiddle but not when i preview my websight from dreamweaver. Huh Intresting? any idea how to fix?